# How to replace only a specific integer with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to replace a given integer with a string in ALL places in my text file. (E.g. in `13 13.0353`, `13` should be substituted with `Al`, providing `Al 13.0353`.) How to perform it using sed?

Answer (score 2):

To replace on field which contain 13 you can do

#### sed

```
sed -E 's/(^|\s)13($|\s)/\1A1\2/g' file
```

#### awk

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==13)$i="A1"}1' file
```

#### perl

```
perl -pe 's/(^|\s)\K13($|\s)/A1$2/g' file
```

#### perl (2)

```
perl -lane 's/^13$/A1/ for @F;print join " ",@F' file
```

---

#### Input

```
baju 213 anyu 13 apu 13 papa 13.0353 12.130353
```

#### Output

```
baju 213 anyu A1 apu A1 papa 13.0353 12.130353
```

Comment: Thank you, you are really thorough. :)

Comment: What a mess but you came thru well. ++

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
echo '13  13.0353' | sed 's/^13/Al/g'
```

Output:

```
Al  13.0353
```

adding `^` will match the start of text

Update:

For removing the first two matches for 13 inside a string use the following:

```
echo 'anyu 13 apu 13 papa 13.0353' | sed -e 's/13/Al/1' -e 's/13/Al/1'
```

Output:

```
anyu Al apu Al papa 13.0353
```

Another example for a global match if there are any two numbers instead of just `13` you could use this:

```
echo 'anyu 13 apu 13 papa 13.0353' | sed -e 's/[0-9][0-9]/Al/1' -e 's/[0-9][0-9]/Al/1'
```

For replacing all `13` in a text:

```
echo 'anyu 13 apu 13 papa 13.0353' | sed -E 's/(^|\s)13(\s|$)/\1Al\2/g'
```

OR this one for matching any other two numbers not just `13`

```
echo 'anyu 13 apu 13 papa 13.0353' | sed -E 's/(^|\s)[0-9][0-9](\s|$)/\1Al\2/g'
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please help me what the situation is if the integers are inside of the lines?

Comment: Could you provide a sample text?

Comment: 'anyu 13  apu 13 papa 13.0353' should be substituted with 'anyu Al  apu Al papa 13.0353'.

Comment: Your output is: 'anyu 13 apu 13 papa AI.0353'.

Comment: `echo 'anyu 13 apu 13 papa 13.0353' | sed 's/13/AI/1'| sed 's/13/AI/1'`

Comment: It would be grateful. :)

Comment: @Roloka, if your requirements has changed - you should specify them in your question

Comment: No, I would like to replace all the matches, as updated in my question. I would say sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes, all '13' should be replaced, not the first two.

Comment: @MostafaHussein The final one will not match if the 13 is at the start or end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
echo "13 anyu 13 apu 13 papa 13.130353 15.13 13" | sed 's/\(^\|\s\)13\(\s\|$\)/ A1 /g' | xargs
```

Matches the number 13 followed by white space or EOL.

Another corner case -- match must now start with white space or SOL as well. Also pipe through xargs to trim leading and trailing white space.

Comment: How to handle the following case: 'anyu 13 apu 13 papa 12.130353'?

Comment: How is that different?     echo "anyu 13 apu 13 papa 12.0353" | sed 's/13[^.]/A1 /g'
anyu A1 apu A1 papa 12.0353

Comment: No, your input is wrong. Correctly: "anyu 13 apu 13 papa **12.130353**.

Comment: Ah - I see what you are saying. Editing answer now.

Comment: `$` in a character class matches a literal `$`, not EOL.

Answer (score 0):

easy:

```
sed -r 's/13([^.])/Al\1/g' file
```

Comment: "echo 'anyu 13 apu 13 papa 13.0353' | sed -r 's/\B13\B/Al/g'" gives the same output as the input.

Comment: Unfortunately, echo 'anyu 13 apu 13 papa 13.130353' | sed -r 's/\B13\B/Al/g'" gives "Al anyu Al apu Al papa 13.Al0353".

Answer (score 0):

i like awk solution:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==13)$i="A1"}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.